does every native currency transaction has 'input' field '0x'
I have reseach for a day to find out which type of token is involved in a transaction.
I know the input field is data used for smart contracts function.
But I'm not sure that every native currency has 'input' = '0x'

That's just a way to represent empty calldata. The input field of calldata is generally written as an hexstring, and an empty hexstring is written as 0x.
You don't have to write anything in calldata because you don't need to pass information through it. The amount of native currency you transfer is already written in the value field.
